# EmberJS "assertion failed: calling set on destroyed object" after unloading and reloading models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having trouble unloading data models and having them properly re-populate when API calls are made.

The models:

```
/* Model Foo */
export default DS.Model.extend({
  bars: DS.hasMany('bar', { async: true })
});

/* Model Bar */
export default DS.Model.extend({
  foo: DS.belongsTo('foo', { async: true, inverse: 'bars' })
});
```

At a point in the app, both foo and bar are unloaded from ember data store and then reloaded from an API call. Like so:

```
/* Unload and reload snippet */
this.store.unloadAll('bar');
this.store.unloadAll('foo');

let bars = this.store.filter('bar', { 
  queryParam: x 
}, function(bar) {
  return x === bar.x
});

let foos = this.store.filter('foo', { 
  queryParam: y 
}, function(foo) {
  return y === bar.y
});

let self = this;
Ember.RSVP.all([foos, bars]).finally(function() {
  self.controller.set('model.foos', foos);
  self.controller.set('model.bars', bars);
});
```

The problem arises in a computed property that is dependent on these model changes.

```
/* Computed property elsewhere in app */
compProp: Ember.computed('foo.bars.[]', function() {
  let tmp = this.get('foo.bars'); /* <-- Error generating line */
  .
  .
  .
})
```

This line gives me the following error:
`Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object: <DS.PromiseManyArray:ember1995>.content = <DS.ManyArray:ember3320>`

Stack trace from error:

```
Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object: <DS.PromiseManyArray:ember1014>.content = <DS.ManyArray:ember1348>
Error
    at assert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor-3e8430b320dbe268f7ee6486de4c6cad.js:23072:13)
    at Object.assert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor-3e8430b320dbe268f7ee6486de4c6cad.js:23285:34)
    at Object.set (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor-3e8430b320dbe268f7ee6486de4c6cad.js:39281:17)
    at Class.set (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor-3e8430b320dbe268f7ee6486de4c6cad.js:52151:26)
    at ManyRelationship._updateLoadingPromise (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor-3e8430b320dbe268f7ee6486de4c6cad.js:152522:33)
    at ManyRelationship.getRecords (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor-3e8430b320dbe268f7ee6486de4c6cad.js:152723:21)
    at Class.get (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor-3e8430b320dbe268f7ee6486de4c6cad.js:152101:60)
    at ComputedPropertyPrototype.get (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor-3e8430b320dbe268f7ee6486de4c6cad.js:34367:28)
    at get (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor-3e8430b320dbe268f7ee6486de4c6cad.js:39184:19)
    at _getPath (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor-3e8430b320dbe268f7ee6486de4c6cad.js:39205:13)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor-3e8430b320dbe268f7ee6486de4c6cad.js:39180:14)
```

Thanks for any help!

Side notes:

- I'm aware `store.filter()` is deprecated. I'm upgrading the app from an earlier Ember version and using ember-data-filter addon for temporary compatibility.
- This was working on Ember 1.13.

### Update

In the interest of not leaving this question open ended, I was never able to find the problem.

The solution for me was removing all `unloadAll()` calls and managing records individually as needed.

Answer (score 2):

This could be caused by any async `set` that occurs on an element that's been destroyed by ember. As such it can be tricky to track down. I usually turn on "pause on **caught** exceptions" in the chrome developer console to find the `set` that caused the issue.

Comment: It looks like the `set` is happening inside Ember. I'm catching it in **has-many.js**. There is an `_updateLoadingPromise` method that executes `this._loadingPromise.set('content', content)`. The `this` seems to refer to the RecordArrayManager of bars. I'm unfamiliar with the inner workings of Ember so I don't know why a `set` is occurring when I'm trying to `get` data.

Comment: If you check the call stack at the exception, you should be able to see exactly where in the code you have a `set` that is attempting to modify data on a destroyed object (probably a component that no longer exists)

Comment: A simple example would be a component that loads some data via ajax and runs `set(this, 'dataField', serverData)` in a callback. If the user goes to another route while the data is loading, the callback will still fire but the component will not exist anymore, so the exception will be caught and logged by ember.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The information in my comment is from using "pause on caught exceptions" and examining the call stack. The only set in the stack trace is the one mentioned in my comment above. I added the exact stack trace as well.

Comment: Okay, I understand things better now. Unfortunately this one looks like it's beyond my skills. I would take this one to the general channel of the ember community slack.